# Pagination separetly is working good. But when i put it inside another code - buttons: first, next, previous, last do not work. What is the reason?

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Controller**

````
```
````

public class ProductTablePageController {

```
 //variables are here
 public Product_Table__c pr { get; set; }
 public List<Product_Table__c> Products { get; set; }
 public string SelectedProductId { get; set; }                    
 public String Name {get; set;}

 public Id editId {get; set;}
 private String sortDirection = 'ASC';
 private String sortExp = 'name';

 public integer numberOfRowsToReturn {get; set;}

 public String searchKey {get;set;}
 //end variables    


  //Pagination start
  public ApexPages.StandardSetController stCon{
  get{
  if(stCon == null){ 
  stCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([Select 
  id,Name,  Amount__c, Price__c,
  ProductType__c, ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c from 
  Product_Table__c ORDER BY Name ASC  limit: numberOfRowsToReturn]));
  stCon.setPageSize(3);        
  }
  return stCon;
  }
  set;
  }




 public ProductTablePageController() {
 setupProduct();
 pr=new Product_Table__c();
 numberOfRowsToReturn= 10;
 }


public List<Product_Table__c> getProducts() {
return (List<Product_Table__c>)stCon.getRecords();
}

Public Boolean hasNext {
get {    return stCon.getHasNext();     }
set;}

public Boolean hasPrevious {
get {    return stCon.getHasPrevious();}
set;}

public Integer pageNumber {
get {    return stCon.getPageNumber();        }
set; }

public void first() {
stCon.first();    }

public void last() {
stCon.last();    }

public void previous() {
stCon.previous();    }

public  void next() {
stCon.next();    }

public void cancel() {
stCon.cancel();    }       
//Pagination end
```

//edit product start here
   public void init() {
   Products = [Select id, Name,  Amount__c, Price__c, ProductType__c,
   ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c  from Product_Table__c ];      }

public PageReference updateNewProductTable()    {
   try{ 
   update products;   }
   catch(DmlException ex){
   ApexPages.addMessages(ex);    }
   init();
   return null;   }
   //end edit product

```
public void setupProduct() {
Products = [Select id, Name,  Amount__c, Price__c, ProductType__c,
ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c  from Product_Table__c ];      }

// insert new product operation
public PageReference insertNewProductTable()    {               
upsert pr;
pr=new Product_Table__c();
Products = [Select id,Name,  Amount__c, Price__c, ProductType__c,
ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c  from Product_Table__c  ];
return null;             } 
// end inserting new product operation

//delete product start here
public void deleteProductTable(){
Products = [Select id, Name,  Amount__c, Price__c, ProductType__c,
ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c  from Product_Table__c
where id = :SelectedProductId];
delete Products;
setupProduct();           } 
//end delete product

 //search product start here
public void searchProducts(){
string searchquery='select Name, Amount__c, Price__c, ProductType__c, 
ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c from Product_Table__c where  name 
like \'%' + searchKey + '%\'   ';
products= Database.query(searchquery);              }
//end search product

   //sorting start here
   public String sortExpression
   {  get
   {  return sortExp;     }
   set{
   //if the column is clicked on then switch between Ascending and Descending 
   modes
   if (value == sortExp)
   sortDirection = (sortDirection == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
   else
   sortDirection = 'ASC';
   sortExp = value;     }   }

   public String getSortDirection()
   {     //if not column is selected 
   if (sortExpression == null || sortExpression == '')
   return 'ASC';
   else
   return sortDirection; }

   public void setSortDirection(String value)
   {     sortDirection = value; }

   public PageReference ViewData() {
   //build the full sort expression
   string sortFullExp = sortExpression  + ' ' + sortDirection;
   //query the database based on the sort expression
   products = Database.query('Select id, Name, Amount__c, Price__c, 
   ProductType__c, ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c from 
   Product_Table__c order by ' + sortFullExp + ' limit 1000');
   return null;   }
    //end sorting                  


    public void updatePage() {
    products.clear();
    products=[select  Name,  Amount__c, Price__c, ProductType__c, 
    ReleaseDate__c,
    Available__c, AddedDate__c from Product_Table__c LIMIT:numberOfRowsToReturn ];   }
```

}

**Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="ProductTablePageController" >
<apex:form id="form">
<apex:pageBlock >

    <!--fields for adding new product-->
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.Name}"  />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.Amount__c}"  />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.Price__c}" />          
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.ProductType__c}"  />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.ReleaseDate__c }"  />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.Available__c}"  />
                   <apex:inputText value="{!pr.AddedDate__c}"  />                                                                   
    </apex:pageBlockSection>   
    <apex:commandButton action="{!insertNewProductTable}"  value="Save"/>                      
    </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
    <!--end fields for adding new product-->



    <!--choose numbers of rows-->
   <apex:selectList value="{!numberOfRowsToReturn}" size="1" >
   <apex:selectOption itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" ></apex:selectOption>
   <apex:selectOption itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"></apex:selectOption>
   <apex:selectOption itemLabel="5" itemValue="5"></apex:selectOption>
   <apex:selectOption itemLabel="10" itemValue="10"></apex:selectOption>
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="form" action="{!updatePage}"/>>
   </apex:selectList><br/>
   <!--end choosing numbers of rows-->





<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Products}" var="pr" id="AccountData" >



    <!--buttons delete and edit-->
      <apex:column headerValue="Buttons">
      <apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!deleteProductTable}"
      onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;">
      <apex:param value="{!pr.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!SelectedProductId}"/>
      </apex:commandLink>
      <apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!updateNewProductTable}" />                             
      </apex:column>
      <!--end buttons delete and edit-->

    <!--output text and editing fields-->
    <apex:column headervalue="Name">
    <apex:outputText value="{!pr.Name}" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.Name}" style="width:30px"/>
    <apex:facet name="header">
    <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Name{!IF(sortExpression=='Name',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
    <apex:param value="Name" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
    </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:facet>
    </apex:column>   

    <apex:column headervalue="Amount"><apex:outputText value="{!pr.Amount__c}"  />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.Amount__c}" style="width:30px"/>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headervalue="Price"><apex:outputText value="{!pr.Price__c}" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.Price__c}" style="width:30px"/>
    <apex:facet name="header">
    <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Price{!IF(sortExpression=='Price__c',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
    <apex:param value="Price__c" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
    </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:facet>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headervalue="ProductType"><apex:outputText value="{!pr.ProductType__c}" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!pr.ProductType__c}" style="width:30px"/>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headervalue="ReleaseDate"><apex:outputText value="{!pr.ReleaseDate__c}" />
    <apex:facet name="header">
    <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="ReleaseDate{!IF(sortExpression=='ReleaseDate__c',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
    <apex:param value="ReleaseDate__c" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
    </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:facet>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headervalue="Available"><apex:outputText value="{!pr.Available__c}" />
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headervalue="AddedDate"><apex:outputText value="{!pr.AddedDate__c}" />
    <apex:facet name="header">
    <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="AddedDate{!IF(sortExpression=='AddedDate__c',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
    <apex:param value="AddedDate__c" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
    </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:facet>
    </apex:column>          
   <!--/end output text and editing fields-->


</apex:pageBlockTable>

     <!--pagination buttons-->
       <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
           <apex:commandLink action="{!first}">First</apex:commandlink>
       <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
       <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
       <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">Last</apex:commandlink>
       </apex:panelGrid>
       <!--end pagination buttons -->

</apex:pageBlockSection> 

   <!--search button and field     -->            
     <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
     <apex:inputText value="{!searchKey}"  />
     <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchProducts}"  />
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>                  
    <!--end search button and field    -->           





</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This code is almost unreadable. Please take some time to format your code using a tool like Prettier (many Java formatters also work). When you have random indentation and brace structure following your logic is extremely difficult.

Comment: Please also cut your code inclusions down to a Minimum Viable Reproduction and provide a detailed description of the problem. It is not clear what you mean by "put it inside another code".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please give me example how code must look.

Comment: As I suggested, please use an automatic formatting tool like Prettier. See the [user guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/prettier). Your code should be _clear, consistent, and structured_.

Comment: I don't understand how to use Prettier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you have has to do with these few lines of code:

```
public List<Product_Table__c> Products { get; set; }
public List<Product_Table__c> getProducts() {
    return (List<Product_Table__c>)stCon.getRecords();
}
```

When you have both a property and a get/set method, the property takes precedence. This means that you're not actually using the standard controller for pagination at all. You must remove the first line, then modify all references to that line to create a new StandardSetController with whatever query is to be used.

You also have the same query in multiple methods, a violation of DRY ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). This should all be consolidated. Finally, you can directly access methods of the StandardSetController, so there's no need to have accessor methods. Example:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!stCon.next}" rendered="{!stCon.hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
```

`stCon` itself should not have this convoluted get/set configuration, just initialize it as you need to. There's no need for "lazy loading" here. You know you're going to need it, you can always predict when it will change, and you always know where it needs to be initialized. Lazy loading is most useful when you don't know if you need a resource, and loading it is expensive. In this case, it's "expensive," but you know you need it.

As a side note, this is a bad idea:

```
   public String sortExpression
   {  get
   {  return sortExp;     }
   set{
   //if the column is clicked on then switch between Ascending and Descending modes
   if (value == sortExp)
   sortDirection = (sortDirection == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
   else
   sortDirection = 'ASC';
   sortExp = value;     }   }
```

Every time the variable is sent back to the server, the setter would be called, and the sort order will be altered. This is probably not what you intended.

Also, you'll have similar problems with:

```
private String sortDirection = 'ASC';
public String getSortDirection()
{     //if not column is selected
if (sortExpression == null || sortExpression == '')
  return 'ASC';
else
  return sortDirection; 
}
```

In addition, never skimp out on curly braces around if statements, even if they are only one line long. This ensures that future modifications won't have unintended effects.

```
if (sortExpression == null || sortExpression == '') {
  return 'ASC';
} else {
  return sortDirection; 
}
```

Finally, clean up your formatting. This code isn't easily readable and certainly does not lend itself to future maintenance.

Comment: 1)Than you very much for your answer. I have a dream to become programmer. This is my first code. I made some formatting and added explanation for every codeblock. Hope now it look better. Can you please give me a reference for page with right formatting for example what i can follow?

Comment: 2) "You must remove the first line, then modify all references to that line to create a new StandardSetController with whatever query is to be used." Can you please give me one example how to modify one reference to that line of code? Because i am not understand how it must work :(